# mongod(v2.6.5) sharded cluster query latency issue?

Tags: linux, node.js, mongodb, amazon-ec2

I am running a node(0.10.26) application which uses a mongo sharded cluster. I am using a three member replica-set as a shard. Here are my other configuration details

**Hardware and OS Settings**

1. EC2: m3.large (RAM: 7.5G)
2. Linux Ubuntu 12.04 (kernel: 3.2.0-69-virtual 64-bit)
3. Disk: 400 G SSD (EBS) (mounted with noatime and readahead setting of 32)

**Application's load pattern**

1. insertion rate = 20-30/second
   Most of the inserts are to the logs collection and they happen 
   all the time.
2. query rate = 50-100 /second
3. updates = ~30 /second

**Mongo**

1. Storage Engine: default (mmapv1)
2. Index size: 3.5G
3. Working set: 270 MB
4. Mongoose version: 3.8.25
5. Mongo version: 2.6.5

My application provides an interface to download the log records as a csv file with a certain filter. When i try the csv download, the application becomes very slow.

After some investigation, I have concluded that the query for the logs is taking very a long time(>2 minutes and sometimes as long as 10 minutes)
Since the database is slow to respond, the application is also slow

**Questions**

1. Why is the query for logs taking long time.

   If I do an explain(), I see that it hits the index.

   mongostat (when run with a 1 second delay) indicates that there 
   are many page faults happening (~800 - 1100)/second. The page 
   faults subside after the query returns. Subsequent queries return 
   in a couple of seconds.

   working set + index size = 3.7 G

   RAM = 7.5 G.

   size of log collection = 50 G
2. Does frequent writes to a log collection impact read operations
   on the same collection. Does this concern apply to my work load ?

Comment: Your have a very detailed question (I am happy to see this from a new user), but can you keep one question per post? In your case there are 4 of them.

Answer (score 0):

According to me lot of things we need to consider here to get resolve the issue. I am not sure what exactly is happening on Mongo side but here are some things that I would look at,

1. You said you are allowing user to provide a filter for logs and create a csv of it and then download.
   In such case, **What is the average size of csv file?**

----  If it is too large then probably I think you are using a cursor to get data and then writing it to a file which can be IO intensive (page faults can prove that.). Instead of this you can check MongoExport and MongoDump options which are designed for efficient bulk operations.

2. you said you are filtering the records, then **What filter you are using?** Is it optimal? Do you have correct indexes?

---- check for filter efficiency. Though you said you are using indexes and query is using index. Still is it possible to add new index which is more efficient? If yes please add it.

3. After matching a record with a filter, **Are you fetching all attributes of that document (log record)?**

---- If answer is yes then are they really required? If answer is no then try to get only required data. Avoid unnecessary processing.

4. Another technique I could think of is, **How sharding is done?**

---- For logs, what are the general search filters(date, error etc.)? In NoSQL Dbs, Requirements/queries/filters should be decided first and then schema/collection etc. If you have not considered that then it is the time because your DB size is small. once it grows you can't do it later.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for reply. 
Avg size of csv file is 3-4 MB.
I think the index is optimal . 
I am not fetching all the attributes. Currently i have only one shard. So all the data is is one shard.

Comment: I think sharding based on date or filter you are using should help. Check for bulk export options also. you can pass filter during export.